# How can i get a specific provider from Django social-auth in a template?

Tags: django, django-socialauth

After installing and setting up social-auth i'm playing around a bit, trying to get the hang of it. I have read the docs, and have used the example project to get it running.

But until now i have no idea how to get information on a certain provider. In the example project the templatetags are always used this way:

```
{% for type, accounts in social_auth.associated.items %}
    {% for account in accounts %}
        {{account.provider}} is connected.
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

What i want to do now is not list all the providers, but check if someone has connected his account to (ie.) facebook. That way i could do something like this:

```
if user==connected_to_facebook
    provide some functionality
endif
```

From the example above i know that social_auth.associated.items contains tuples of `(type,account)`, where "facebook" would then be in a list with all values for `account.provider`.

What comes to my mind is this:

```
{% if "facebook" in social_auth.associated.items.accounts.provider %}
```

which, obviously, is not going to work. I think this one will work, but not return the result i'm after:

```
{% if "facebook" in social_auth.associated.items[1].provider %}
```

Is there some functionality in Django that i can do this with? Maybe some special templatetag i'm missing? Or is this functionality already built into social_auth, and i somehow missed the documentation? Or, my worst suspicion, is it really really obvious, and i'm just ...

Any help extremely welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"social_auth" is not some tuples inside of tuples, it is a dictionairy:

```
{'not_associated': {}, 'backends': {'oauth2': ['facebook']},
 'associated': {'oauth2': [<UserSocialAuth:testuser>]}}
```

That certainly makes a lot more sense, but still does not lead anywhere. So i took a look at a user that has not associated his account yet, and there that dictionary looks like this:

```
{'not_associated': {'oauth2': ['facebook']}, 'backends': {'oauth2': ['facebook']},
 'associated': {}}
```

Now i found something usefull:

```
{% if "facebook" in social_auth.not_associated.oauth2 %}
{% else %}
    provide facebook functionality
{% endif %}
```

That works. All you have to know is what type of authentication the backend you are looking for uses, then make sure it is not in the not_associated field of social_auth.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs to create a disconnect URL, here's the hack-y code I came up with, where `providers` is a list I'm passing in like `["Facebook", "Twitter"]`

```
{% for p in providers %}
    <h2>Link {{ p }} Account</h2>
    <p>Use your {{ p }} account to log in
    {% if p|lower in social_auth.not_associated %}
        <a href="{% url socialauth_associate_begin p|lower %}?next={{ request.path }}" class="off">No</a>
    {% else %}
        {% for item in social_auth.associated.all %}{% if item.provider == p|lower %}
        <a href="{% url socialauth_disconnect_individual p|lower item.id %}" class="on">Yes</a>
        {% endif %}{% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

It seems like there should be a dictionary of associated accounts instead of doing this, but I couldn't figure it out. Not sure what will happen if a user managed to authorize their account twice.