# Given a User object, how can I list all social associations (for creating a disconnect URL)?

Tags: django-socialauth

I've inherited a project using Django Social Auth.  Given a User object, how can I determine which if any social associations are active?

My goal is simply to build a form letting the user disconnect from any backend:

```
Your login: XXXX
Macebook: [disconnect]
Tweeter: [disconnect]
```

I know I need to build the right URL ('disconnect/(backend)/(association_id)'), but I can't figure out how to iterate over the proper list of the User's associations.

For a related question see [How can i get a specific provider from Django social-auth in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014501/how-can-i-get-a-specific-provider-from-django-social-auth-in-a-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example application shows how to do it. Here's a snippet:

```
{# assuming that social_accounts = user.social_auth.all() #}
{% for social in social_accounts %}
    <a href="{% url "socialauth_disconnect_individual" social.provider social.id %}">Disconnect {{ social.provider }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```